# Modify and read from an atomic variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, atomic

A class has the following member,

```
std::atomic<int> clientId{0};
```

And given the following inside it's member function,

```
int currentId = ++clientId.load();
```

Is there a race condition here? I am trying to do something similar to generate clientId's. Multiple threads could execute this part of the code. Can a thread that has incremented clientId and before it tries to load() and get a copy, another thread increment the same and thus end up with a race condition?
If yes, is protecting with a mutex the best way using an ordinary int and getting a copy inside the mutex?

Please explain.

Comment: `std::atomic<>::load` does not return a reference, so you are simply incrementing a temporary, that is no race condition, but I doubt this is what you want...

Comment: You probably simply want `int currentId = ++clientId;`.

Comment: Put your `clientId` declaration outside of the function. Putting it inside a function means that a new object will be created every time, defeating it's purpose. Answering your question, it's the job of the `atomic` to prevent race conditions and the such.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can clientId be incremented once again by another thread before it's coped into currentId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::atomic<int>::load()` does not return a reference, so you are not incrementing the current value of `clientId`, you are incrementing the temporary returned by `load()`.

You need to do:

```
int currentId = ++clientId; // no .load()
```

There are [overloaded operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) for `std::atomic`. The memory order for the pre-increment operator is [`std:: memory_order_seq_cst`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)<sup>1</sup>, which says:

> A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order (see Sequentially-consistent ordering below)

So you are safe from data-race condition here.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The standard says that `++clientId` is equivalent to `fetch_add(1) + 1`, and the default memory order for `fetch_add` is `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, Can clientId be incremented once again by another thread before it's copied into currentId?